# What is the difference between fopen modes "r+" and "rw+" in PHP?

Tags: php, fopen

Many answers here in Stack Overflow use `fopen($file, "rw+")`, but the [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) doesn't list the `"rw+"` mode, there's only the `"r+"` mode (or `"w+"` mode).

So I was wondering, **what does the `"rw+"` mode do? What's the difference between `fopen($file,` `"rw+"` or `"r+"`?** I'm asking this because there is no documentation on the `"rw+"` mode.

One approach is to consider that the modes are *additive*, but I couldn't find any mention of combining modes in the `fopen` manual page (besides, what's the sense of combining `"r"` with `"w+"`, if `"w+"` already makes it readable?). But most importantly, *`w+` mode truncates the file, while `rw+` does not truncate it* (therefore, they cannot be additive). Probably there is no `rw+` mode, despite its use by Stack Overflow users. Maybe it works because the parser ignores the "w" letter, as the `rw+` mode appears to be === `r+`?

To clarify my question: *what is the `"rw+"` mode*, that is, how does it differ from other modes? I only received two answers in the comments: either that I should check the documentation (I already checked and rechecked) and a wrong answer, which said it is equal to `"w+"` (it isn't). `"w+"` truncates the file, while `"rw+"` doesn't.

Here's a script for testing (it proves that `w+` truncates the file, but `rw+` doesn't):

```
<?php 
$file = "somefile"; 
$fileOpened = fopen($file, "w"); 
fwrite($fileOpened, "0000000000000000000"); 
fclose($fileOpened);  

$fileOpened = fopen($file, "rw+"); 
fwrite($fileOpened, "data"); 
fclose($fileOpened); 
$fileOpened = fopen($file, "r"); 
$output = fgets($fileOpened); 
echo "First, with 'rw+' mode:<br>".$output; 

$fileOpened = fopen($file, "w+"); 
fwrite($fileOpened, "data"); 
fclose($fileOpened); 
$fileOpened = fopen($file, "r"); 
$output = fgets($fileOpened); 
echo "<br><br><br>Now with only 'w+' mode:<br>".$output; 
?>
```

Comment: The manual _does_ list those. It's `r` and `w+`. It's simply a combination.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you! But what does it mean? What's the difference? I mean, if "w+" is used, then it is already readable. What's the sense in putting "r" too?

Comment: Yes, in this case, you should be able to omit the `r`-flag. You can see the difference between `r+` and `w+` in the manual. `w+` does more.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson OK, so there's no difference, it should only be `"w+"`? And how did you know about the possibility of combination of modes? I re-read the whole fopen part, couln't find it

Comment: @MagnusEriksson By the way, you're answer is wrong, it is not equal to `"w+"`. It seems to be equal to `"r+"`. I just changed my code and the results went wrong with `"w+"` instead of `"rw+"`

Comment: It looks like the `+` means "read", so if you add `r` to the mode, I would guess you're saying "open a file for writing, reading and reading". You're effectively asking for permission to read twice, which would be redundant.

Comment: I've cast a reopen vote, as I agree with the request to reopen (it's perhaps borderline, but I do think it has a specific answer). However please do not use posts to complain about voting decisions, especially if your tone is angry or sarcastic - that does not belong here. There is a Meta site where you are welcome to appeal voting decisions if you wish (we encourage it where a poster is not convinced by the close reason).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @halfer ! Unfortunally, `rw+` is not the same as `w+` plus the `r` mode. From my tests, it seems to be the same as the `r+` mode, and it has nothing to do with the `w` mode. I'm sorry if my question is still unclear, could you please let me know what makes it a borderline case? For me it was clear, since I want to know what the undocumented `rw+` mode does. I need to finish a job for this weekend, but I'll edit my question soon and post it in the Meta site.

Comment: I regarded it as borderline on the basis that the answer I thought we had was not very useful (i.e. that you were requesting a permission twice). However since you believe you have found differences in behaviour then the question is much more worthy of being opened (and it is reopened now in any case). I think there's too many **Edit** addenda so I will try to iron those out, but maybe you could edit the question to show your tests? That would make for a much clearer question.

Comment: Thank you for the edits @halfer ! I'm still busy on something I need to deliver as soon as possible, but I'll make the edits this week. The main test was quite simple: my code breaks if I substitute `rw+` for `w+`, but works exactly as it's supposed to if I substitute it with `r+`. The reason is simple: `w+` truncates the file, but `rw+` doesn't, it behaves as far as I could tell identically to `r+` (that does not truncate the file). I ran some other tests on this but pretty basic stuff, always got `rw+` === `r+`

Comment: This question is being discussed [in this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350512/472495).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I think you have pretty much figured this out. Although I guess, you want authoritative answer.

It is true that the documentation does not mention `"rw+"`. Yet, there is something better: [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src)!

---

### The Rabbit Hole

I had a hard time trying to navigate the source code until I found the article series PHP's Source Code For PHP Developers ([Part 1](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/03/phps-source-code-for-php-developers.html), [Part 2](http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/16/Understanding-PHPs-internal-function-definitions.html), [Part 3](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/03/phps-source-code-for-php-developers_21.html), [Part 4](http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html)). *I know the links jump between two sites, that series is hip like that. By the way, I didn't find the announced Part 5.*

**Note**: Those articles are old, they are talking about PHP 5.4.

Let us see what `fopen` actually does... let us fall into the rabbit hole...

First we look at the [function definition](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L870) (which I found following the advice of the linked part 2 above). I notice it uses [`php_stream_open_wrapper_ex`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L889), which I [found elsewhere](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_streams.h#L573), it just uses `_php_stream_open_wrapper_ex` which we find in [stream.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/streams.c#L2010).

What does `_php_stream_open_wrapper_ex` do with `mode`? [It passes it to `stream_opener`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/streams.c#L2055-L2057).

Looking for the definition of `stream_opener` took me to the type [`php_stream_wrapper_ops` in php_streams.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_streams.h#L134).

[Searching for uses of the type `php_stream_wrapper_ops`](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=php_stream_wrapper_ops&type=) leaded me to [plain_wrapper.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/plain_wrapper.c).

There are actually a lot of initializations of `php_stream_wrapper_ops` that allow to open different things. We are looking at php_fopen_wrapper.c because it has an initialization of `php_stream_wrapper_ops` where `stream_opener` is `php_plain_files_stream_opener`.

*We are getting there...*

`php_plain_files_stream_opener` is [further down in the same file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/plain_wrapper.c#L1073). [It delegates to `php_stream_fopen_rel`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/plain_wrapper.c#L1080).

[`php_streams.h` defines `php_stream_fopen_rel`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_streams.h#L68) by using `_php_stream_fopen`. Which is [back on plain_wrapper.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/plain_wrapper.c#L975).

Finally, [`_php_stream_fopen` calls `php_stream_parse_fopen_modes`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/plain_wrapper.c#L984). Which will take the string and output some flags, Yay!

---

### Wonderland

Let us have a look at [`php_stream_parse_fopen_modes`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/plain_wrapper.c#L66):

```
PHPAPI int php_stream_parse_fopen_modes(const char *mode, int *open_flags)
{
    int flags;

    switch (mode[0]) {
        case 'r':
            flags = 0;
            break;
        case 'w':
            flags = O_TRUNC|O_CREAT;
            break;
        case 'a':
            flags = O_CREAT|O_APPEND;
            break;
        case 'x':
            flags = O_CREAT|O_EXCL;
            break;
        case 'c':
            flags = O_CREAT;
            break;
        default:
            /* unknown mode */
            return FAILURE;
    }

    if (strchr(mode, '+')) {
        flags |= O_RDWR;
    } else if (flags) {
        flags |= O_WRONLY;
    } else {
        flags |= O_RDONLY;
    }

#if defined(O_CLOEXEC)
    if (strchr(mode, 'e')) {
        flags |= O_CLOEXEC;
    }
#endif

#if defined(O_NONBLOCK)
    if (strchr(mode, 'n')) {
        flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    }
#endif

#if defined(_O_TEXT) && defined(O_BINARY)
    if (strchr(mode, 't')) {
        flags |= _O_TEXT;
    } else {
        flags |= O_BINARY;
    }
#endif

    *open_flags = flags;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

For abstract, this is what it does (ignoring the details):

1. It takes the first character of `mode` and checks if it is `r`, `w`, `a`, `x`, `c`. If it recognizes any of those, it sets the appropriate flag. Otherwise we have a `FAILURE`.
2. It looks for `+` somewhere in the string and sets the appropriate flags.
3. It looks for `e`, `n` and `t` (depending on Preprocessor Directives) somewhere in the string and sets the appropriate flags.
4. Return `SUCCESS`.

---

### Back to the real world

You asked:

> What is the difference between fopen modes “r+” and “rw+” in PHP?

Nothing. PHP only cares that the string starts with `"r"` and has a `"+"`. The `"w"` is ignored.

**Final note**: While it is tempting to play with it and write stuff like `"read+"`, be careful with that, because those letter could someday have some meaning. It would not be forward compatible. In fact, in some context, `"e"` already has a meaning. Instead, I suggest, sticking to the documentation.

---

*Thanks for the excuse to give a look at the PHP source code.*

Comment: So technically you could pass `"read+"`, or `"rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr+"`

Comment: Only words that do not contain `e`, `n` or `t` are equivalent to plain `r`. So `"rrrrrrrrrrrrr"` yes, but `"read"` or any of @Theraot's or @Nisse's suggestions, no. Unless you do actually want the extra flags.

Comment: I know I'm supposed to avoid "thanks" comments, but this answer is awesome, thank you very much for it! It also sheds light on other languages (e.g., C, where I think the parser also ignores the "w' https://adelekeadelaja.blogspot.com.br/2015/06/c-programming-file-rw-mode-not-working.html ), I think people naturally go for "rw" because it's more intuitive to think of "read-write", but they forget about the plus (I think universally "w+" implies "read"). But I digress, thanks a lot again!